# divergent series and natural log difference can be rational?

Tags: number-theory

EDIT1:

Apart from harmonic series is there another divergent series whose limiting difference with natural logarithm is rational?

Comment: What is the difference of a series?

Comment: Referrence is to difference of sum of two diverging series to $n$ terms when $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: If the question was whether the Euler-Mascheroni constant must be irrational because every member of the sequence $a_n=1+1/2+1/3+\cdots +1/n-\ln(n)$ is irrational - no, this conclusion is not valid. It is an open question whether the Euler-Mascheroni-constant is irrational.

Comment: I edited to include a divergent series and  natural log as what I meant. Suspect the question is still not posed properly.

Comment: @Narasimham The answer below indicates the point very good. If you are not content with this answer, add in your question what you are still missing.

Comment: This is clear... Somehow  it felt $a_n,b_n$ are correct but trivial examples.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if a series diverges, then it doesn't really have a limit (unless you'd say $\infty$ is a limit).

If you on the other hand mean having a series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$, with difference $\sum (a_n-b_n)$, then sure: take $a_n=1+\tfrac1{2^n}$ and $b_n=1$ so that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n-b_n)=1$$

is rational, yet both $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ diverge.